# jqGrid freeze rowheader (rownum)

Tags: performance, jqgrid, freeze, distortion, rownum

I am trying to freeze rownum column of grid. Because I have replaced text of rownum with meaningful row description.
I took help from jqgrid freezing columns demo. But it is not working out for rownum column.
My grid loads local array data and using version jQgrid 4.3.2
Aftert his I tried another approach to freeze first column with property

```
'frozen: true' and then I call function  $(grid_selector).jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');
```

and I get below issues:

- The grid loads becomes exceptionally slow (tested in IE, Firefox)
- After much wait when page loads, the row header alignment is distorted. All rowheaders get shifted one step up and overlaps Caption div.

Row1Header goes into Caption place - Row2Header goes into Row1 and so on..

My ultimate requirement is to freeze rowheaders. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks